# Не виден PATH-путь

Tags: python, path

Скачал Пython 2.7.9. Файл `pip`, который мне нужно запустить, находится в папке `C:/Python27/Scripts`. Если напрямую ввести путь, то все работает, если же я ввожу этот путь в переменную `PATH` и в консоли ввожу только название скрипта, то выскакивает ошибка:

> "pip" не является внутренней или внешней
>   командой, исполняемой программой или пакетным файлом.

Такое ощущение, что этот файл не видно, хотя для Python, папку которого я точно так же добавил в `PATH` все работает. Что нужно исправить?

Comment: Слэши, может, на обратные заменить? *Файл pip, который мне нужно запустить* Этот файл - исполняемый, или запускается через ассоциацию?

Comment: Перезапустите откройте консоль (закройте и откройте)

Comment: Консоль перезапустил уже раз 10, не помогло, слэши изначально стояли обратные. Просто как мне кажется, проблема не в том, что я что-то не так синтаксически написал, потому что PATH путь для интерпретатора : C:\Python27 - работает

Comment: Расширение .exe, так что по идее - исполняемый

Comment: Сам PATH покажите-то

Answer (score 0):

Напишите в консоль только

```
path
```

и после того убедите себя, что на выводе (между другими путями) тоже `C:/Python27/Scripts`.

Может быть, что вы включили эту путь в `PATH` *только в консоли* - но в консоли меняется *только временная копия переменной `PATH` (которая после выхода с консоли *уничтожается*).

Нужно включить её на *системном уровне* (как системную или пользовательскую переменную среды) - <kbd>Windows</kbd>+<kbd>Pause</kbd>, затем последний пункт влево наверху, затем последняя кнопка в диалоговом окне, и т.д.